# T-Sql SPROC - Parse C# Datatable to XML in Database (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

#### Scenario

I've got an application written in C# that needs to dump some data every minute to a database. Because its not me that has written the spec, I have been told to store the data as XML in the SQL Server database and NOT TO USE the "bulk upload" feature. Essentially I just wanted to have a single stored procedure that would take XML (that I would produce from my datatable) and insert it into the database.....and do this every minute.

#### Current Situation

I've heard about the use of "Sp_xml_preparedocument" but I'm struggling to understand most of the examples that I've seen (My XML is far narrower than my C Sharp ability).

#### Question

I would really appreciate someone either pointing me in the direction of a worthwhile tutorial or helping explain things.

EDIT - Using (SQL Server 2005)

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005, there is an XML datatype. It's worth having a read of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx) MSDN overview of XML support in SQL Server 2005.

You can pass an XML variable into (e.g.) a stored procedure very easily, and the data within it can be easily queried. Have at look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx) article with examples.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds like you need to understand serialization first.

1. Figure out what the format of the xml should look like.
2. Code your datatable serialization mechanism per xml format.
3. Code your sproc to take the xml and insert it into final table.

This link looks like a decent example of serializing a dataset.

http://www.diranieh.com/NETSerialization/XMLSerialization.htm

Also, for learning purposes... try to take a look C#/Linq and try to get an idea of how this query language allows you to perform CRUD statements against xml (and other objects) in memory.